# jquery escaping special charatcers while looping items in select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you help me on below issue with special characters.
I have a value to check in the select drop down and remove it. But thye the select text is having special character in it, so some how it is not working.
Please help.

```js
selArray = ['option (1)']
$('selArray').each(function(index, item) {
    $('#sel option[value="+item+"]').remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
    <option value="opt100">opt100</option>
    <option value="option (1)">option (1)</option>
    <option value="33">opt33</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What are you expecting item to be?   - and what is selArray for? it doesn't seem to be in use?

Comment: sorry I corrected that....so did you get my problem am facing now?

Comment: Ive added an answer that corrects the syntax issues you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you. What I do is reduce your selArray into a string using [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), and then the special characters are escaped with backslashes (as is the convention for regular expressions) using [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), and then use a regular expression to check if it matches the value of the current select element in question.

See my code:

```js
selArray=['option (1)']
$('#sel option').each(function(){
  var test = selArray.join('|').replace(/\(|\)/gi, '\\$&')
  var re = new RegExp(test, 'i')
  if(re.test($(this).val())) $('#sel option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove()  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
<option value="opt100">opt100</option>
<option value="option (1)">option (1)</option>
<option value="33">opt33</option>
</select>
```

In the line:

```
var test = selArray.join('|').replace(/\(|\)/gi, '\\$&')
```

The regex `/\(|\)/gi/` looks for every instance of either an open or closed parentheses. The replacement regex `\\$&` is what essentially places a backslash before each match. If you're unfamiliar with regular expressions, I'd recommend [RegExr](http://regexr.com), it's a very useful resource.

This line:

```
var re = new RegExp(test, 'i')
```

Creates a new regular expression using the (now escaped) string formed from joining the selArray. It is then tested against the value of each select element on the following line:

```
if(re.test($(this).val())) $('#sel option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove()
```

wherein if the condition returns true, the select element in question is deleted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```js
selArray=['option (1)']
$('#sel option').each(function(index,item){
   a = $(this).val();
  //console.log(a);
  if($.inArray(a,selArray)!== -1)
  {
    //console.log($.inArray(a,selArray));
    $(this).remove()
  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
<option value="opt100">opt100</option>
<option value="option (1)">option (1)</option>
<option value="33">opt33</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer following my comment above, some of your syntax was incorrect.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sel" id="sel">
    <option value="opt100">opt100</option>
    <option value="option (1)">option (1)</option>
    <option value="33">opt33</option>
</select>

<script>
    selArray = ['option (1)'];
    $(selArray).each(function(index, item)
    {
        var opt = $('#sel').find('option[value="' + item + '"]');
        $('#sel').find('option[value="' + item + '"]').remove();
    });
</script>
```

Explanation: you don't need to quote selArray when turning into a jQuery object.

Also, you were missing quotes when concatenating the selector.

The above code will work for you.